# For loop advances two numbers instead of one

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

When i put in the first input it prints the second and the third at the same time. Console:

```
Please enter the grade for course 1
A
Please enter the grade for course 2
Please enter the grade for course 3
```

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class MyGradeLoops {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
int grade;
for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the grade for course " + i);
    grade = System.in.read();
    }
    System.out.println("Thank your for submitting your grades");
   }
  }
```

Comment: Which is the question? What did you expect your program to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.in.read();` will read the next byte from the user input. When you type a number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it would count for at least three bytes (with the two additional bytes corresponding to `\r` and `\n` new line characters).

You can simply use a `Scanner` instance and read the integer using `Scanner#nextInt()`.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the grade for course " + i);
    grade = in.nextInt();
}
```

If `System.in.read()` is a requirement and the grade is input as a string, here's a (sort of hacky) way to do it:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    String grade = "";
    System.out.println("Please enter the grade for course " + i);
    char c;
    while((c = (char) System.in.read()) != '\n') {
        grade += c;
    }
    System.out.println(grade);
}
```

Comment: I'm required to use the System.in.read() method for my class. It also needs to be a letter and I dont think that can take letters?

Comment: @anthonycorrado See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109996/parse-input-without-using-anything-but-system-in-read). `System.in.read` reads input as bytes so you would have to convert to a `char` and read until the new line is hit.